# Retrieving East Asian language data from SQL SERVER database

Tags: php, json, sql-server-2012

Currently I am getting the data from **SQL Server** using **PHP 3.5** and I am returning in **Json** format. But in my database I have data in different languages like **Chinese, Thai, Japanese, Korean** and etc. when I return the data it shows in this format:  **??????**

How can I show the data in original format?
below is my code:

```
$query = "SELECT                   
               [name]
              ,[venue]                
              FROM tablename
              WHERE id = '2'";

/**********************************************/
//Just for the Purpose of Count Number of Rows
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );
/******************************/

#Query the database to get the user details. 
$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);  

$arr = array();
#If no data was returned, check for any SQL errors 
if ($res == false) 
{ 
   echo 'Query not Executed : '.  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}
else
{       
    while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($res, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $arr[] = array(
        "name" => $obj['name'],
        "venue" => $obj['venue']
        );
    }
}

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
#Output the JSON data 
echo json_encode($arr);
exit();


sqlsrv_free_stmt($res); // Closes a statement. Frees all resources associated.
sqlsrv_close($conn);    // Closes a connection. Frees all resources associated.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried the code below?

```
echo json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: **@Sirinat Paphatsirinatthi** my current PHP Version is **3.5** and i don't think so it support **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**

Comment: Could you please update the version to the latest version? I think it will be better.

Comment: **@Sirinat Paphatsirinatthi** 
currently it is a bit difficult because i don't have the Server Access

Comment: Oh, it's difficult to solve this problem because of your outdated PHP version. Waiting for another one. Hope you can solve it soon

Comment: **@Sirinat Paphatsirinatth** OK do one thing please like this post so i can go to chat as i have less Reputation to communicate in Chat over Stackoverflow. Thanks

Comment: **@Sirinat Paphatsirinatth** i apply on the PHP new version but i am getting this error: 


**Use of undefined constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE - assumed 'JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE'**

Comment: Whats your PHP version now ?

Comment: **@*Sirinat** PHP 5.4